# How can I open chrome extension in a tab instead of popup

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Installed chrome extension can be opened as popup only and disappear on blur. I want it to be opened in a tab instead of popup. How to do that?

Chrome version:  107.0.5304.110,
Ubuntu,
extension Tronlink

Comment: Which extension? Which version of Chrome? Which OS?

Comment: @Peregrino69 check edit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not all the extensions work the same but you can do this steps

- right click on it's pop up and select inspect
- go to console tab and type `document.URL` hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
- add that link to a bookmark bar and use it

Comment: Just to add, some extensions have right click disabled. In that case, just hit F12 to open the DevTools.

Comment: You can actually right-click on the extension icon in the toolbar and choose "Inspect pop-up" to jump directly to the DevTools and the extension cannot disable that behaviour.